# Call actionresult logoff in the index page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have made a login page and a user can login. No I want the user to logoff.

I have this in my AccountController:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

But how can I call this actionresult in my index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this

**From a view**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account")
```

or

```
<a href="@Html.Action("LogOff", "Account")">Log Out</a>
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Account/LogOff")">Log Out</a>
```

I don't recommend the last one however because it doesn't take into consideration action and controller routing. I only included it here as a last resort option.

**From another action**

You could also call the action directly from code like you would any normal class method, should you need to do that. Like so:

```
class ActionController : Controller
{
    // ...
    public ActionResult AnotherAction()
    {
        // Do stuff here
        return LogOff(); // You don't have to return the results if they're not needed
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this you can call this actionresult

```
 <a href="@Href("~/Account/LogOff")">Logout</a>
```

Keep a breakpoint in your LogOff action in your Account controller and see what is happening..

Answer (score 0):

its a best practice to make logoff method a Post method , so i suggest to use this form :

```
<form method='post'>
<button type='submit'>LogOff</button>
</form>



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
//Do LogOff Stuff.
}
```